# About primitive roots of $p$ less than $\frac{p-1}2$.

Tags: congruences, primitive-roots

If all the residues of $p$, from $2$ to $\dfrac{p-1}2$ can be expressed as $(2^A)(3^B)(5^C) \pmod p$ for some integers $A$, $B$, $C$ then is it true at least one of $2$ or $3$ or $5$ is a primitive root$\pmod p$?

Comment: No. For example, that condition holds for $p=41$, but none of $2$, $3$, or $5$ is a primitive root $\mod 41$.

Comment: One shouldn't expect something like this to be true without a conceptual reason. In general $\langle a,b,c\rangle$ generating a cyclic group is not enough for that group to be generated by any of $a$, $b$ or $c$ individually.

Comment: Is 7^20 = 1 mod 41? Is it true for any w (such that 1 < w < 41) that w^20 =1 mod(41)?

Comment: 11^4 = 4 mod(41) so 11^20 = 4^5 = 2^10 mod(41) 2^10 = -1 mod(41) Therefore 11^20 = -1 mod(41). 2, 3, and 5 are not primitive roots mod(41). IF there exists a,b,c all elements of integers | (2^a)(3^b)(5^c) = 11 mod( 41) then 11^20 should be congruent to 1 , but its not its congruent to -1. So 41 does not follow the conditions of my question. I was looking for primes where all the residues less than a given prime( candidate) can be expressed as congruent to the product of exponents of 2,3, and 5.

Comment: If all the residues of a prime p can be expressed as a product of exponents of 2,3,5 mod p then one of 2,3,or 5 is a primitive root mod p. ( 41 does not follow these conditions)

Comment: If neither 2,3  are primitive roots then  2^((p-1)/2) = -1 mod p and 3^((p-1)/2). Let m be a primitive root mod p ;  assume there exists r,s | (2^r )(3^s)  = m mod p. Then m^((p-1)/2) =-1 mod p yet (2^r)(3^s) to the exponent (p-1)/2 is 1 mod p. So if all residues mod p can be expressed in the product of exponents of 2 and 3 then either 2 or 3 is a primitive root ( or both) mod p.

Comment: 11 can not be expressed in the form (2^a) (3^b) (5^c) mod 41 so the prime 41 is not a counterexample..